# Load select option from JSON data according to previous select data

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

What I am doing wrong in this code:

```
<form action="">
    <select class="input-xlarge required" id="inputGender" name="inputGender">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="m">male</option>
        <option value="w">female</option>
    </select>

    <select class="input-xlarge" id="inputWeight" name="inputWeight">
        <option value="">select</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Book" />
</form>


var data = [
    [
        {"ID":"1", "desc":"(12)"},
        {"ID":"2", "desc":"(5)"},
        {"ID":"6", "desc":"(15)"}
    ]
    [
        {"ID":"0", "desc":"(49)"},
        {"ID":"7", "desc":"(5)"}
    ]
];


$("#inputGender").change((function() {
    var $persons = $("#inputWeight").empty();
    $.each(data[$(this).val() - 1], function() {
        $persons.append("<option value=" + this.ID + ">" + this.desc + "</option>");
    });
});

);
```

When the value `m` is selected I want to populate this data:

```
[
    {"ID":"1", "desc":"(12)"},
    {"ID":"2", "desc":"(5)"},
    {"ID":"6", "desc":"(15)"}
]
```

On selecting id `#inputWeight`. or if `w` is selected then show this:

```
[
    {"ID":"0", "desc":"(49)"},
    {"ID":"7", "desc":"(5)"}
]
```

...but it's not working.

Some idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is what's wrong in your JS :

```
$.each(data[$(this).val() - 1], function() {
```

`$this.val()`, in this context, means the value of `inputGender`, which can be "m" or "w". You must have pasted this code from somewhere else, because it assumes integer values. Try changing your data to this :

```
var data = {
    m: [{"ID":"1","desc":"(12)"},{"ID":"2","desc":"(5)"},{"ID":"6","desc":"(15)"}],
    w: [{"ID":"0","desc":"(49)"},{"ID":"7","desc":"(5)"}]
};
```

and then you can use `$(this).val()` to get the array you want :

```
$("#inputGender").change(function() {
    var $persons = $("#inputWeight").empty();
    $.each(data[$(this).val()], function() {
        $persons.append("<option value=" + this.ID + ">" + this.desc + "</option>");
    });
});
```

See it working live in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqxfc/1/).

Comment: Boss that is absolutely perfect? but if I need to access the data from the other file like from data.php...how could I access that???

Comment: the data.php is the same content as var Data...that we have it here. the difference is we just access it from different file.

Comment: Well it depends, do you mean you have a `data.php` file that spits out some JSON? Then I guess you could load it with `var data =  $.getJSON('data.php');`? You might want to post a new question for that (or look for similar questions and their answers, I'm sure your problem has been answered before). If your original question was solved, please mark my answer as accepted to close it.

Comment: can you see error on this code, if($('#inputWeight').length==1){ $('#inputGender').change(function(){ $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "data.php", data: { prs_gender: $('#inputGender').val() }).done(function( msg ) { var wcs = $.parseJSON(msg); console.log(wcs); $('#inputWeight').html('');$('#inputWeight').append('<option value="">'+'<?=_('[Select]')?>'+'</option>');$.each(wcs, function(){
$wc=$(this); $('#inputWeight').append('<option '+selected+' value="'+$wc[0].ID_wcl+'">'+$wc[0].wcl_desc+'</option>'); })
                    })        
                })
            }

Comment: I don't see any problems, other than a missing `}` at the end, or a `selected` variable which I don't know where it's coming from, and the fact that you're using `$wc[0]` in your loop, which seems strange... -then again, I don't know what your JSON data is like.

Comment: [{"ID":"1","desc":"(12)"},{"ID":"2","desc":"(5)"},{"ID":"6","desc":"(15)"}],
 [{"ID":"0","desc":"(49)"},{"ID":"7","desc":"(5)"}]

Comment: my JSON looks like above with out m and w

Comment: the above code is not working, could I please ask other question and you can see it there please?

Comment: here is the new question, please check it out...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314288/according-to-two-inputes-populate-select-option-with-ajax-and-php